# SSH Unsupported KEX algorithm 3des-cbc?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to SSH into one IP (I don't have access to that device, so can't modify anything from the other side). ~/ssh/config file:

```
Host {HIDDEN}
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    KexAlgorithms +3des-cbc
```

Error:
`Unsupported KEX algorithm "3des-cbc"
/Users/gintas/.ssh/config line 36: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+3des-cbc'.`

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

```
KexAlgorithms +3des-cbc
```

`3des-cbc` is not a key exchange algorithm but a cipher. You need to use

```
Ciphers +3des-cbc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to configure it "permanently" via a file you can also use `-c 3des-cbc` or `-o Ciphers +3des-cbc` as the argument to the `ssh` command.